# Do i always need to update edmx on stored procedure change?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I have this stored procedure code change where previously the query was

```
update Table set date = getdate()
```

changed to

```
update Table set date = dateadd(hh,15,getdate())
```

After making this change to stored proc do I need to update edmx in my code ?
Or I can directly make change into the Prod database and the application will have changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external interface of the stored procedure does not change (i.e. No changes to the parameter list of the stored proc, and the outputs are in the same format) then the EDMX does not need to change. So, if this change is only on the internals of the stored procedure you should be fine.